# How to fetch arrays with string in php

Tags: php

how can i fetch data in an arrays  with gives null value if null

here is my data I `var_dump($showStatus);` I want to print out .   `$showStatus[0]['title']`

```
string(0) ""
    array(2) {
      [0]=>
      array(7) {
        ["id"]=>
        string(1) "1"
        ["container_id"]=>
        string(1) "3"
        ["title"]=>
        string(51) "waitting"
      }
      [1]=>
      array(7) {
        ["id"]=>
        string(1) "2"
        ["container_id"]=>
        string(1) "3"
        ["title"]=>
        string(72) "getting"
      }
    }
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      array(7) {
        ["id"]=>
        string(1) "4"
        ["container_id"]=>
        string(1) "7"
        ["title"]=>
        string(51) "getting"
      }
    }
```

The reason that I've string because in my models I want to print `""` or `NULL` when it don't have data here is my models

```
public function showStatus($id){
    $sql = 'SELECT * FROM status WHERE container_id = '.$id;
    if($this->query_rows( $sql )) {
        return $this->query_rows($sql);
    } else {
        return "";
    }
 }
```

I try to use

```
foreach ($getListData as $k) {

}
```

but it said Warning: Invalid argument supplied for `foreach()`

Comment: can you just print_r($showStatus); and check the array .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try this:**

```
if(!empty($getListData) )
{
    foreach ($getListData as $k) {
       print_r($k);
    }    
}
else {
    echo "NULL";
}
```

Comment: thank you , so i've to check !empty first before I use foreach lopp right ?